# How do I get the data returned from this ajax call to use as vars?

Tags: jquery

New to Ajax calls. Need some pointers to start my learning but want to do it with a real example.

This link: http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/david.tumblr.com/info?api_key=API_KEY

returns this to my browser which is a good example of data I'll be using:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": 200,
        "msg": "OK"
    },
    "response": {
        "blog": {
            "title": "David\u2019s Log",
            "posts": 3981,
            "name": "david",
            "url": "http:\/\/www.davidslog.com\/",
            "updated": 1348785660,
            "description": "\u201cMr. Karp is tall and skinny, with unflinching blue eyes and a mop of brown hair. He speaks incredibly fast and in complete paragraphs.\u201d \u2013&nbsp;NY&nbsp;Observer",
            "ask": false
        }
    }
}
```

I think I could use this as a start but definitely open to other ways:

```
var tumblrURL = "david.tumblr.com";

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + tumblrURL + "/info",
    data: {api_key: "MY_PRIVATE_API_KEY"},
    dataType: "jsonp",
});​
```

But I am lost as to proper ways to parse out and get the different bits returned and use them as vars or for tests in the call.

For example, how do I get "status" or the "name"?

When the status is a 200 then I would want to make a var out of the name ("david") and use it for other options.

Or, if the status is a 404 then I would want to do something else (like return an error).

Please, no flames. I'm trying to learn and if I get a few examples or pointers I will be able to move on to more interesting stuff. I'm OK with other aspects of jQuery so those issues should be fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jQuery.Ajax` function [takes an optional function parameter `success`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

You could set this to your own function, which would automatically execute once the request succeeds - providing you with the entire JSON blob you receive as a normal Javascript object. In your case, you could get the status of the request at `data.meta.status` - or the name at `data.response.blog.name`.

Note that jQuery also allows for error handlers on Ajax requests, called automatically in a similar way: `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`.

---

Example code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + tumblrURL + "/info",
    data: {api_key: "MY_PRIVATE_API_KEY"},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Do whatever you'd like in here with your data
        console.log("Got a response from " + data.response.blog.name);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Do whatever you'd like in here with your ERROR data
        alert("Got an error: " + textStatus);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Any chance for a simple example perhaps in a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks! This should give me a start. Where does "textStatus" come from? Do I need to set that as a var prior?

Comment: Nope - notice that `data`, `textStatus`, `jqXHR`, etc... are defined in the functions - meaning that they're arguments. When jQuery calls these functions automatically, it calls them with those arguments prepopulated.

Comment: Ah, yes. I noticed while testing and you were writing. More caffeine.

Comment: The only thing that doesn't fire is the alert. I get this at the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Ah - the alert will only fire if your request to the API comes back as a non-200 response code. (Usually.) That error sounds like the data you're receiving back isn't of the same form that you expect - namely, it indicates that the `blog` object has no `name` parameter. Try logging the entire `data` object to the console so you can inspect it.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly the kind of guidance I needed. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Generally after a ajax call happens , if the request is a success i.e, if you get the response
you access it in the success callback function...

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + tumblrURL + "/info?api_key=MY_PRIVATE_API_KEY",  // The url you want to pass
    dataType: "jsonp",  // The type of format expecting
    data: "{}",  // Your data to be sent
    success: function(result) {   // If ajax is a success
       alert('Ajax request Success !!');
   },
    error: error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  //If error in ajax
        alert('Error occured  : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

This is just the basic setup of ajax request.. You have many more options whih you can look up in [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) .

The jsonp data you get in the callback look's like the one in the example..

Here result is a object .. You generally use **.** notation or [] notation to access the result.

To get the data **inside meta** you use `result.meta.status`
To get the data **inside name** you use `result.response.blog.name`

You can always use console.log( result.meta.status) to log the value onto the console.

Comment: Thanks! Should give me a good start. One questions: Which data am I sending (in your example)? Then, looks like some caffeine and some reading.

Comment: That is optional..  The data should be in the from of json object , the parameters you want to send to the server on which you want to execute something and return back

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful. I'm on my way now. Yay!